# How to check if string contains C# string.Format placeholder

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-formatting

How can I simply check if a string contains `{x}` (`x` can be any number)?

I guess there is some simple RegEx to do this.

```
"This string contains {0} a placeholder".HasPlaceholder == true
```

and

```
"This string contains no placeholder".HasPlaceholder == false
```

Comment: Really, just a number inside `{...}`? Did you really have any problem with such a basic regex? I assumed you need to match any `string.Format` placeholders at the beginning, but now it seems just a dupe of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970).

Comment: Does this string contain a placeholder? `"A {{0}} B"`?

Answer (score 5):

You can write a simple extension and use a regex:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool HasPlaceholder(this string s)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(s, "{\\d+}");
    }
}
```

This regex works *only* for the placeholders you specified (containing only a number).

For a full placeholder you would need something like `"{\\d+(,-?\\d+)?(:[A-Z]\\d*)?}"`. But this still needs refinement. See ["Standard Numeric Format Strings"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a full list of valid symbols.

You can use this extension like this:

```
string s = "This string contains {0} a placeholder";
if (s.HasPlaceholder())
    Console.WriteLine("Contains placeholders");
```

Comment: See [*Standard Numeric Format Strings*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for the possible formats that the pattern should cover to answer the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew included your link, thanks. But the question explicitly asks for `{anynumber}`, not for a regex valid for all possibilities

Comment: If it is, then the question must be closed as a dupe of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970).